# How to configure Shiro + Spring MVC when @Controller REDIRECTS to a login page

Tags: spring-mvc, http-headers, spring-webflow, shiro

I have a typical Spring MVC + GWT architecture with Apache Shiro as a security layer.

Problem:
No matter what protocol is used for a request to the App server, pages should be returned in the protocol specified in the request's "X-Forwarded-Proto" header (so, app server can receive a HTTP request, but if the header says HTTPS, it should respond using HTTPS). Obviously, the configuration specified in the Shiro-Spring tutorial won't work as it has nothing to do with the protocols (login.jsp will be returned using the protocol used in request):

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
  <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
  <property name="loginUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>
  <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
    <value>
        /** = authc
    </value>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
  <property name="realm" ref="myRealm"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myRealm" class="com.myapp.security.DBRealm">
   <property name="credentialsMatcher" ref="sha256Matcher"/>
</bean>
```

Possible solution:

Use @Controller to REDIRECT to the login view with the specified protocol:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView doLogin(HttpServletRequest req) throws MalformedURLException {
  URL originalURL = new URL(req.getRequestURL().toString());
  return new RedirectView(new URL(req.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto"), originalURL.getHost(), "/login.jsp").toString());
}
```

and change the loginUrl in shiro configuration to point to /login, so that @controller catches it:

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
  <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
  <property name="loginUrl" value="/login"/>
  ... leave everything else the same
</bean>
```

But with this configuration, although I get the same login page, the *myRealm* (com.myapp.security.DBRealm) is not triggered at all (meaning, the credentials are not checked), and login always fails. Seems like the redirected page loses the "hook" to the realm.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is failing is because the Shiro `authc` Filter (a [FormAuthenticationFilter](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authc/FormAuthenticationFilter.html)) expects the `loginUrl` to be the one where the login attempt occurs.

That is, when `authc` filters a request that matches the `loginUrl`, it will automatically support form-based authentication.  Because you are redirecting the end-user to a URL that does not match the `loginUrl` (i.e. `loginUrl`=`/login`, but you redirect them to `/login.jsp`), the `authc` filter won't perform a login.

Your best option IMO:

Subclass `FormAuthenticationFilter` and override the `redirectToLogin` method to use your `X-Forwarded-Proto` logic.  Then redefine 'authc' to be your custom subclass.  For example, using shiro .ini:

```
    [main]
    ...
    authc = com.foo.my.FormAuthenticationFilterSubclass
```

Also, if you want this behavior in Shiro directly (so Shiro looks for that header when performing a redirect by default) so you can remove your subclass, please open a feature request in [Apache Shiro's Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO).

Comment: Thanks, Les. I'll try that. Having Shiro "natively" support X-Forwarded-Proto might not be the most useful feature (not sure how many people have the similar case), but being able to set separate URLs - one for "redirectToLoginURL", and the other for "performAuthenticationURL(s)" - might really be helpful.